# C# Unity Prefabs wont show up on Canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, overlay, invisible, prefab

My scene is 2D
My Canvas is set to Screen Space - Overlay. (I don't want to change that)

I can see my prefabs shoing up in the hierarchy but they're not visible.
I bet it has something to do with the camera view, they're behind the camera or they're not attached to the correct thing like it has to be an UI item. but I don't know. Been trying to figure this out for 8 hours straigt.

Please help. Im new to Unity and C# so it could be a simple thing?

Comment: I think I got one step closer now. So when I check my clone in the hierarchy, I can see that the Parent has the correct Layer and Tag but the Clone still fall under Default Layer. This is not good. How do I lock the damn thing to inherit a specific Layer and maybe also a Tag?

Answer (score 0):

solved it.

It was a mistake that I tried and forgot about. I had changed my camera target display but now its set back to 1 and everything works. solved, issue closed.

Answer (score 0):

- Check if you are applying changes to the `prefab` not the `instances`(clones) of `prefab`.
- Check the Z axis of your `gameobject/prefab` if you're making a 2d game.
- Check if prefab is within [clipping planes](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html) of your camera

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out late last night. I made a new camera, had that to only show my prefab stuff and the main cam to see everything else. but at one point I changed the display to 2 and forgot about it...hours later I saw it and flipped back to 1 and problem solved...very annoying but a great release when I finally got it to work.